# Importing private keys into wallet - does the bitcoin disappear from the original wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, private-key-export, private-key-import

If I import a bunch of private keys into a new wallet, will the funds be removed from the original wallet? Or do they both somehow point to the same money?

In my case, I wish to move funds from Bitcoin Core wallet to an Exodus wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoins are never actually in a wallet. Bitcoins sit in the blockchain. Many copies of that blockchain resides in nodes (computers). Simply put, your wallet merely is a list of addresses on which according to the blockchain are (fractions of) bitcoins stored.

You can have as many of the same wallet s you like. When they all contain the same addresses, they will show the same balance as they are all looking to the same blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

if you Imported a private key into another wallet it will shows the exact amount as that of the original wallet and the coins will still be in the original wallet and you can only spend it with the private key of the original wallet, but if you sweep the wallet the coins are moved from the original wallet to the new wallet